# Help with this mechanism?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I know that the bottom reaction is probably elimination, but I've never seen Na2CO3 being used as a reagent in this context. I've only taken Organic chemistry I and II, so that's the extent of my synthesis reaction knowledge. Any help would be appreciated. Sorry about the red squiggly box around Na2CO3; I'm not very familiar with ChemDraw.

[image: Mechanism]

Comment: Are you sure you have drawn the sodium benzenesulfonate salt correctly, or do you mean sodium benzenesulfinate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to assume that there is an error in the reaction diagram (either by the OP or in the original question) and the starting material is sodium benzenesulfinate (PhSO2Na) NOT sodium benzenesulfonate (PhSO3Na).

Sodium benzenesulfinate is nucleophilic through sulfur and has been shown to displace halogens from alkyl halides [example](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/244759160_Organic_Reactions_in_Ionic_Liquids_An_Efficient_Method_for_the_Synthesis_of_Aryl_Sulfones_by_Alkylation_of_Sodium_Arenesulfinates_with_Alkyl_Halides).

Nucleophilic displacement of the primary bromide gives an alkyl sulfone with a beta leaving group. The methylene protons alpha to the sulfone are sufficiently acidic to be removed under basic conditions (though I have never seen carbonate used in this context) to drive the elimination giving the alkene.

If the reaction is genuinely run with sodium benzenesulfonate I have no idea what is going on.